# grouping a hash based on parameters ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

so i have the following

```
[{:item=>"x"}, {:item2=>"x"}, {:item3=>"x"}, {:item=>"x"},{:item3=>"x"}]
```

I want to get this split into groups,

so each group starts at item and ends at item3, item2 could be missing

ideally i want

```
{:item=>"x",:item2=>"x",:item3=>"x"} & {:item=>"x",:item3=>"x"}
```

So in a real example:

An 3 items need to be posted but I get an array from an excel spreadsheet

```
name: blah
id: blah
color: blah

name: blah
date: blah
size: blah

name: blah
id: blah
date: blah
color: blah
size: blah
```

I need to post each record, given I have an array like above is there some way to group/split the array on a given hash element key field?

Comment: This would be much easier with real data. For example, do you always have these three, or can there sometimes be four or five, do their names actually increment sequentially, are your keys actually symbols like this, can the values differ, what is the final goal you have in mind, it is `{:item=>"x",:item3=>"x"}`?

Comment: yes i need to either iterate over the first array and execute a method every time i reach a new item. A new item is defined started at :item and ends until I reach a new :item key.  I hoped there was an easier way than iterating over and over

Comment: Could you maybe make a test/spec showing what you expect as inputs and outputs?

Comment: there is allways an :item after a :item3?

Comment: Is the array always ordered like this? Could they be in a different order? If so, how can you determine what should go with what?

Comment: yes maybe, but item 3 might not be there, the only consistency is Item, the first key

Comment: Yes Dave always the same order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A functional approach, get the indexes where the `:item`s are and split there:

```
hs = [{:item=>"x"}, {:item2=>"x"}, {:item3=>"x"}, {:item=>"x"},{:item3=>"x"}]
indexes = hs.map.with_index { |h, i| i if h.first[0] == :item }.compact
(indexes + [hs.size]).each_cons(2).map { |from, to| hs[from...to].reduce(:merge) }
#=> [{:item=>"x", :item2=>"x", :item3=>"x"}, {:item=>"x", :item3=>"x"}]
```

If you prefer a more declarative approach (I do), add some abstractions to your extensions library so you can write:

```
indexes = hashes.find_indexes { |h| h.first[0] == :item }
hashes.split_at(*indexes.drop(1)).map { |hs| hs.reduce(:merge) }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is really delimited by double line break, you should take advantage by splitting first by paragraph, then by line, then by the colon. Then you don't have to worry about missing data and can blindly fill in key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
input = [{:item=>"x"}, {:item2=>"x"}, {:item3=>"x"}, {:item=>"x"},{:item3=>"x"}]

res = []
input.each do |element|
  if element.keys.first == :item
    res << element
  else
    res.last.merge! element
  end
end

puts puts res.inspect # => [{:item=>"x", :item2=>"x", :item3=>"x"}, {:item=>"x", :item3=>"x"}]
```

Answer (score -2):

Pure awesomness of Ruby:

```
arr = [{:item=>"x"}, {:item2=>"x"}, {:item3=>"x"}, {:item=>"x"}, {:item3=>"x"}]
arr.each_slice(3).map { |a| a.inject(&:merge) }
=> [{:item=>"x", :item2=>"x", :item3=>"x"}, {:item=>"x", :item3=>"x"}]
```

Comment: I am afraid what the OP showed was an example, this only works for that particular input.

Comment: @tokland OP said it always have the :item

Comment: Sorry, I meant: `[{:item=>"x"}, {:item3=>"x"}, {:item=>"x"}, {:item2=>"x"}, {:item3=>"x"}]`

Comment: note: the downvote was not mine, but did you see the problem?

Comment: I see. But first version of question was a little bit unclear.